# Cannot connect remote SQL Express server (Linux) to power BI using DirectQuery

Tags: sql-server, linux, powerbi

Dear stackoverflow community,

I have a problem using Direct Query connect in Power BI. I have an SQL Express server running on a remote server with a Linux operating system. I connect to this server using a VPN. I can connect to this SQL server with my local MS SQL Express installation no problem. I can also import the data to my local Power BI desktop installation using Get Data>SQL Server>Import.

However when I try to use Direct Query, it fails after executing for a while and setting up the Direct Query connections. I receive the following Error Message:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
> Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
> Server);The network path was not found. The exception was raised by
> the IDbConnection interface."

[It's also interesting that it appears like something is loading in the fields pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1D3s.png)

I feel it could be a problem with allowing remote connections in the Linux remote MS SQL Express Server, but have found no way of allowing this in Linux. On my Windows installation it's no problem.

I'm really excited to solve this issue and start building my dashboard. But I need a live connection for that...

Thank you for your time reading this and your replies in advance.

Comment: Where is the PowerBI environment running? Is it locally, in the cloud, a server in your domain? If any of the latter, then the other host is going to have no path to a host you can only access over the VPN.

Comment: PowerBI is running locally, on my desktop.

Comment: If PowerBI is running entirely locally it would be abke.to use that VPN, which implies the connection details you entered are wrong.

Comment: I agree, but I think I wouldn't be able to import the database if that was the case. Or does using Directquery use a different port? I made a connection over the regular port 1433.

Comment: try to completly rebuild your directQuery and double check the sql server address/instance name in the connection string

Comment: I mean, I can get the data and table structure from the sql server instance, doesn't that verify the connectionstring is correct? What do you mean with connectionstring? IP address + portnumber ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by using the 64 bit version Power BI from the microsoft store and not adding the portnumber when making the sql connection. I recommend admins not to delete this as finding this solution wasn't too straightforward.